# aws sam LambdaLayer deploying for every new build

Tags: aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have a Resource in my template.yml:

```yaml
  MyLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ContentUri: layers/my-layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
```

This is my Makefile:

```
  build-MyLayer:
      mkdir -p "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/python"
      cp *.py "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/python"
      python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/python"
```

Every time while I doing `sam build` and then `sam deploy` the layer MyLayer deploys to the AWS and new version creating. Even if I do not change the code of the MyLayer module.

How can I disable a layer new version creating in every deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which responds to my requirements.
I am create a separated folder with `template.yaml` which describes a one resource (AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion) only. When I need release a new version I make a build that resource